# Switch - how to enable default animation in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-switch

I have a standard unaltered Switch class on every list item in a `RecyclerView` (in order to toggle an item on or off). Usually switches in Android have a nice default animation with the switch sliding into position and a small bubble animation appears. In my case, the switch just jumps into the final position without any animation. Here is my layout for it:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/alarm_toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:checked="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

The property `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` does not have any effect. Tried on Android M and O. How can I enable the standard animation?

Comment: Does toggling the switch trigger any java code (especially anything that would call e.g. `notifyDataSetChanged()` or similar)?

Comment: In fact, yes, there is a long-running operation that is run in an AsyncTask, but apparently it is blocking the UI thread somehow. I commented out the code, and the animation is working. Please post an answer, and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If toggling your `Switch` executes any java code, it's possible for this to affect whether or not animations play. Perhaps you have something that calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` (or similar), which will cause an immediate re-draw of the entire `RecyclerView`. Or perhaps you're accidentally blocking the UI thread, which would prevent animations of any sort.